# how to submit form using AJAX in HTML

Tags: ajax

My web service is running on 8080 port. This is developed using gSoap in C++. I have also implement post/get method in my c++ code. Now i want to submit form using AJAX with POST. And also send some data to web service.
I have written below code for submit form.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/myWebservice",
    cache: false,
    data: MyData,
    success: function () {
             alert("send Successful......");
    }      
});
```

Comment: And what is your question now? You posted now an example of the jQuery ajax function...

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know you should bind that call to any of your click or any event. or call it inside any function. Your code is correct.